# How to execute shell command from editor window?

Tags: shell, ansi-term

I have two windows open - one in editor mode with some SQL, bash, etc and the other in ansi-term. I want to mark my text and then execute it in the ansi-term window. Yes, I could make a shortcut involving copy paste but I was curious if there was anything canonical. Copy-paste also forces me to switch out of terminal mode and into editor mode in ansi-term

Answer (score 2):

Emacs supports sending the region/buffer to the interpreter. This is supported in various modes, including [python](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python-running-emacs.html), [haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Emacs/Inferior_Haskell_processes), [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Running-Octave-from-Within-Emacs.html), and even in shell scripts. Unfortunately, they keybindings are different in every mode.

For shell scripts (`sh-mode`), you can use `C-c C-n` to send the current line, or the highlighted region to the inferior shell. Unfortunately, it looks like it is hardcoded to use `shell`, not `ansi-term`.

For SQL (`sql-mode`), similar features are available under `C-c C-r` (send region) and `C-c C-b` (send entire buffer). See the mode help of sql-mode for mode keybindings. You may need to install an interpreter that sql-mode can use (or configure sql-mode to use the right interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
(defun send-region-to-ansi ()
  "If region active, send it to ansi-term buffer."
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p) 
      (send-region "*ansi-term*" (region-beginning) (region-end))))
```

Maybe you don't even want to mark a region. I use a function that marks the current paragraph automatically.

```
(defun send-paragraph-to-ansi ()
  (interactive)
  (mark-paragraph)
  (send-region "*ansi-term*" (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (deactivate-mark))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most basic command, independent of a major mode, is `shell-command-on-region`or `M-|`.

The buffer where the output from above command is send to is `*Shell Command Output*`.